# Replace form by another one on click with javascript

Tags: javascript

I need your help for my code :

I've got two forms, one to register and another one to log in.

I would like to replace the log in form by the register form when the user clicks on "Sign up" link. Same if he already has an account, I would like to replace the register form by the log in form when clicking on the "log in" link.

Here my two forms :

```
         <!-- Login form -->
         <div class="log form" id="login">
            <h2>Log in</h2>
            <form class="form_log">
                 <div>
                     <label for="login">Login : </label>
                     <input type="text" name="login" id="login" required>
                 </div>

                 <div>
                     <label for="password">Password : </label>
                     <input type="text" name="password" id="password" required>
                 </div>

                 <div>
                     <input type="submit" value="Connexion">
                 </div>

                 <p>Don't have an account ? <a href="#" onclick="display('#register')">Sign up</a></p>
             </form>
          </div>

          <!-- Register form -->
          <div class="register form" id="register">
             <h2>Sign up</h2>
             <form class="form_register">
                <div>
                   <label for="login">Login : </label>
                   <input type="text" name="login" id="login" required>
                </div>

                <div>
                   <label for="password">Password : </label>
                   <input type="text" name="password" id="password" required>
                </div>

                <div>
                   <input type="submit" value="Connexion">
                </div>

                <p>Already registered ? <a href="#" onclick="display('#login')">Log in</a></p>
              </form>
          </div>
```

Script :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      function display (open){
         $(open).css("display", "block");
         $(".form").not($(open)).css("display","none");
      }
 });
```

I think something is missing or wrong in my code but I don't know exactly what.

Comment: Just put `display` function outside `$(document).ready`

Comment: Right, it was the correct solution, it works, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Toggle can do toggle between the display of form

```js
function display() {
   $("#login").toggle();
   $("#register").toggle();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Login form -->
         <div class="log form" id="login" style="display: none">
            <h2>Log in</h2>
            <form class="form_log">
                 <div>
                     <label for="login">Login : </label>
                     <input type="text" name="login" id="login" required>
                 </div>

                 <div>
                     <label for="password">Password : </label>
                     <input type="text" name="password" id="password" required>
                 </div>

                 <div>
                     <input type="submit" value="Connexion">
                 </div>

                 <p>Don't have an account ? <a href="#" onclick="display('#register')">Sign up</a></p>
             </form>
          </div>

          <!-- Register form -->
          <div class="register form" id="register">
             <h2>Sign upn</h2>
             <form class="form_register">
                <div>
                   <label for="login">Login : </label>
                   <input type="text" name="login" id="login" required>
                </div>

                <div>
                   <label for="password">Password : </label>
                   <input type="text" name="password" id="password" required>
                </div>

                <div>
                   <input type="submit" value="Connexion">
                </div>

                <p>Already registered ? <a href="#" onclick="display('#login')">Log in</a></p>
              </form>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. What wrong with your code is you don't put your function inside a ready() event handler.

```js
function display(divId) {
  $('.form').hide();
  $(divId).show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Login form -->
         <div class="log form" id="login" style="display: none">
            <h2>Log in</h2>
            <form class="form_log">
                 <div>
                     <label for="login">Login : </label>
                     <input type="text" name="login" id="login" required>
                 </div>

                 <div>
                     <label for="password">Password : </label>
                     <input type="text" name="password" id="password" required>
                 </div>

                 <div>
                     <input type="submit" value="Connexion">
                 </div>

                 <p>Don't have an account ? <a href="#" onclick="display('#register')">Sign up</a></p>
             </form>
          </div>

          <!-- Register form -->
          <div class="register form" id="register">
             <h2>Sign upn</h2>
             <form class="form_register">
                <div>
                   <label for="login">Login : </label>
                   <input type="text" name="login" id="login" required>
                </div>

                <div>
                   <label for="password">Password : </label>
                   <input type="text" name="password" id="password" required>
                </div>

                <div>
                   <input type="submit" value="Connexion">
                </div>

                <p>Already registered ? <a href="#" onclick="display('#login')">Log in</a></p>
              </form>
          </div>
```